# Paste text into Excel comment VBA

Tags: excel, paste, vba

I cannot find or create VBA code to allow pasting copied text from one cell in another sheet(sheet2) into a previously created comment in another sheet(sheet1).

Here is the code I have successfully compiled thus far, and I am stuck on how to get the text found into the comment box.

```
Sub For_Reals()

'Add Comment
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").AddComment
Range("F2").Comment.Visible = False

'Find Value in Sheet2 based on Value from Sheet1
Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If

'Copy Value 4 cells to the right of found Value
Selection.Offset(0, 4).Copy

'Need Code to paste copied value in previously created comment

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than copy and paste the cell value into the comment, you create the text at the same time as creating the comment box.  If a comment box already exists an error is raised - so remove any comment boxes in that cell beforehand.

The VBA help gives this as an example:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("E5").AddComment "Current Sales"
```

So with this in mind, this code will do the trick:

```
Sub For_Reals()

    'Find Value in Sheet2 based on Value from Sheet1
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
            'Remove any existing comments, create comment and add text.
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").ClearComments
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").AddComment Rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
                Range("F2").Comment.Visible = True
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Darren, Very much appreciate the response and for simplifying the code. I am getting a Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error when I attempt your version. The bug appears to be in the line:                                      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").AddComment Rng.Offset(0, 4).Value                                                                                                     Any thoughts on why I am recieving the error? I am running VBA off Microsoft Excel 2013.  Thanks, Jeff

Comment: It looks like it throws an error if rng.Offset(0,4) is a blank cell.  I'd add another variable "Dim sCommentText As String" and set this to hold the value "sCommentText = rng.Offset(0, 4).Value" and then use this to add the text "Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").AddComment sCommentText"
It doesn't seem to mind the blank cells then.

Comment: Darren, That did the trick! I can't tell you how awesome that is, so thank you very very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Final code I ended up with is below. Added a loop to run through the column, and added a second reference to pull both the definition and description into the comment. Thank you Darren Bartrup-Cook for helping me out when I was stuck!

```
Sub Add_Comment_As_Def_Desc_Reference()
'Posted by Jeff Barrett 2015-04-10    

    Dim FindString1 As String
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim sCommentText1 As String
    Dim sCommentText2 As String
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim cmmt As String
    Dim i As Integer        
    str1 = "Definition: "
    str2 = "Description: "            
 'Loop Code, must specify range for i based on # of FieldAlias    
Sheets("Fields").Select
Range("F4").Select
For i = 4 To 59          
    'Find Definition & Description in NASDefs based on Value from FieldAlias
    FindString1 = ActiveCell.Value
    If Trim(FindString1) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("NASDefs").Range("C:C")
            Set Rng1 = .Find(What:=FindString1, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        End With
    End If    
            'Remove any existing comments, create comment and add text in FieldAlias
            If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
                ActiveCell.ClearComments
                sCommentText1 = Rng1.Offset(0, 4).Value
                sCommentText2 = Rng1.Offset(0, 5).Value
                ActiveCell.AddComment.Text Text:=str1 & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & sCommentText1 & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & str2 & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & sCommentText2
                ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
                ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle                    
                'Format lines of text
                    With ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame
                            .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 5
                    End With
                Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
'End Loop
ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=0).Select
Next i
  'Resize Comment to fit text
  'posted by Dana DeLouis  2000-09-16
  Dim MyComments As Comment
  Dim lArea As Long
  For Each MyComments In ActiveSheet.Comments
    With MyComments
      .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
      If .Shape.Width > 300 Then
        lArea = .Shape.Width * .Shape.Height
        .Shape.Width = 300
        ' An adjustment factor of 1.1 seems to work ok.
        .Shape.Height = (lArea / 200) * 0.6
      End If
    End With
  Next ' comment

End Sub
```